# 400 Bad Request выдает Nginx

Tags: nginx

В логе Nginx'a периодически видно ошибку 400 Bad Request.
Что это значит и как от нее избавиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка значит, что клиент пытается отправить слишком большой запрос. Ничего страшного. Если слишком много таких ошибок, попробуйте настройку [large_client_header_buffers](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0+400+Bad+Request+%D0%B2+Nginx).